# How do I make a transparent canvas in html5?

Tags: html, canvas

How can I make a canvas transparent? I need to because I want to put two canvases on top of one another.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Canvases are transparent by default.

Try setting a page background image, and then put a canvas over it. If nothing is drawn on the canvas, you can fully see the page background.

Think of a canvas as like **painting on a glass plate**.

To clear a canvas after having drawn on it, just use `clearRect`:

```
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Canvas has a black background on mobile so layering canvases doesn't work there. (At least on Chrome for Android)

Comment: So much for standards, as usual.

Comment: I think these answers are missing the point. Similar to the above question, I want to have two layered canvases: the bottom one has a static image, but the top one will have animated sprites. This top layer needs to have a transparent background, but also has to be 'cleared' and redrawn with every animation frame. Yes, it starts transparent by default, but how do you reset it to transparent and the start of every new  animation frame?

Comment: This is how to clear a canvas anytime : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing

Comment: Since you got soo many upvotes Can you at least answer the question too? How do you make a non transparent canvas transparent?

Comment: I ran into problems because I was using <canvas/> instead of <canvas></canvas>. Only the latter works.

Answer (score 66):

I believe you are trying to do exactly what I just tried to do:
I want two stacked canvases... the bottom one has a static image and the top one contains animated sprites. Because of the animation, you need to clear the background of the top layer to transparent at the start of rendering every new frame. I finally found the answer: it's not using globalAlpha, and it's not using a rgba() color. The simple, effective answer is:

```
context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
```

Answer (score 56):

Iif you want a particular `<canvas id="canvasID">` to be always transparent you just have to set

```
#canvasID{
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Instead, if you want some particular elements inside the canvas area to be transparent, you have to set transparency when you draw, i.e.

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
```

Comment: FYI: `opacity` changes will have no effect if there is a background fill in the canvas.

Answer (score 3):

Paint your two canvases onto a third canvas.

*I had this same problem and none of the solutions here solved my problem. I had one opaque canvas with another transparent canvas above it. The opaque canvas was completely invisible but the background of the page body was visible. The drawings from the transparent canvas on top were visible while the opaque canvas below it was not.*

Answer (score 3):

Just set the background of the canvas to transparent.

```
#canvasID{
    background:transparent;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not work in all situations, context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height) is the solution that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If you're exporting your canvas, remember to export as `png`!!

Been there, failed at that xD

Comment: This!!!! I've been hitting my head here hours and the issue is that I was exporting as jpeg. Blerg.

Answer (score 0):

`fillStyle` might not be what you are looking for because it can't really clear the canvas; it will either paint it with a solid color or with a transparent color which doesn't paint anything.

The trick that did for me relies on an implementation detail about the `<canvas></canvas>`. They "reset" when resized (tested on Chrome and Firefox):

```
canvas.width = canvas.width
```

This phenomenon initially struck me as a very annoying behavior, but it also became the only way I know to hard reset the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal proof of concept of the default transparency of canvases, and using `position: absolute` to stack them on top of each other:

```js
const canvases = [...Array(4)]
  .map(() => document.createElement("canvas"));

canvases.forEach((canvas, i) => {
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const saturation = 100 / canvases.length * (i + 1);
  ctx.strokeStyle = `hsl(160, ${saturation}%, 60%)`;
  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeRect(i * 50 + 10, i * 15 + 10, 100, 80);
});
```

```css
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't comment the last answer but the fix is relatively easy. Just set the background color of your opaque canvas:

```
#canvas1 { background-color: black; } //opaque canvas
#canvas2 { ... } //transparent canvas
```

I'm not sure but it looks like that the background-color is inherited as transparent from the body.