# Force canvas transparency

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Already looked here-- [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815166/how-do-i-make-a-transparent-canvas-in-html5)

I'm trying to get the black background on my canvas to be semi-transparent, but this attempt --

```
context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
```

-- didn't seem to change anything.

[Play with my codepen!](http://codepen.io/livingcanvas/pen/wigso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your css rule `#canvas` is not getting applied.
In your javascript, you create a tag `canvas` but don't assign an id to it. Try assigning an `id="canvas"` and your `#canvas { opacity:0.4; }` will get applied.

```
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id="canvas";
```

Comment: beautiful! any way to make just the black background fade and the blue animated ripples stay at full opacity?

Comment: So, canvases are transparent by default. If all you want is a faded black background, how about having your canvas wrapped in an element that has `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` (or whatever alpha you want) and don't fill your canvas with any color? And then remove the opacity from your `#canvas`

Comment: yes! I was actually trying to hunt down where the canvas background color is set so I can remove that... here's the updated codepen. your suggestion totally worked for the change in opacity! http://codepen.io/livingcanvas/pen/hJtmg

Comment: Humm, it seems that the whole pixel manipulation is happening in your `loop()` function. I suggest you look deeper into that and figure out where/how the calculation is done so that instead of making the pixel, darker/brighter, you set its alpha channel. Maybe [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/pixels.html) can help you better understand that pixel manipulation function.

Comment: @Carey http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/ZE2rT/ check out line 168. I removed the css opacity, and do the alpha via the pixel buffer.