# Getting the canvas to be transparent

Tags: javascript, css, babeljs

So I found a wave style I liked on codepen. I'm not gonna go through design my own I want to focus on the backend of my website rather then UI. But still want stunning UI. Anyways I want to know if anyone would know how to make the canvas so that it is transparent.

I have an app that I've created its a simple splash page. I just want to make it so when a user presses more info the wave moves up and allows the user to accept terms of use...

Here is a link to the code pen:

https://codepen.io/RTarson/pen/375507d01a90fd265b030abec49b78ac

```
/*========================================
   Wave
   ========================================*/

$.wave = function (color, amp, height, comp) {
  $.ctx.beginPath();

  var sway = $.simplex.noise2D($.goff, 0) * amp;

  for (var i = 0; i <= $.count; i++) {
    $.xoff += $.xinc;

    var x = $.cx - $.length / 2 + $.length / $.count * i,
    y = height + $.simplex.noise2D($.xoff, $.yoff) * amp + sway;

    $.ctx[i === 0 ? 'moveTo' : 'lineTo'](x, y);
  }

  $.ctx.lineTo($.w, -$.h); // -$.h - Vertically reflection
  $.ctx.lineTo(0, -$.h); // -$.h - Vertically reflection
  $.ctx.closePath();
  $.ctx.fillStyle = color;

  if (comp) {
    $.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = comp;
  }

  $.ctx.fill();
};
```

Again I'm looking for how to get the canvas to display what ever is behind it. The rest is straight forward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a transparent canvas in html5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815166/how-do-i-make-a-transparent-canvas-in-html5)

Comment: @David784 Already read that before showing me. didn't help

Comment: If I comment `//$.ctx.fillStyle = "#182645";` in your code pen, I can see your background through the waves. Your canvas is transparent, but the contents aren't.

Comment: @David784 yes but I only need the white part to be transparent

Answer (score 0):

Each canvas pixel has four 8-bit bytes of color information, one for red, one for green, one for blue and one for opacity. An opacity byte value of 0 is fully trasparent and a value of 255 corresponds to fully opaque.

All canvas pixels are transparent initially: the byte buffer for the canvas is zero filled.

If want the wave to be semi transparent, the colors used to create it need to have opacity information in their [color value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#RGB_colors). Color strings show in the pen don't specify any alpha channel value and default to fully opaque.

Please check the MDN link, but I suspect the most reliable browser support will be for CSS color values in the format "`rgba( red, geen, blue, alpha)`".