# Why flickering rectangle (drown by canvas) doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, canvas, drawing, flicker, rect

I just started to learn a little bit about canvas!

I want to draw rectangle that flickers (shows/hides/shows/hides/shows...) after set time interval.

If I remove `setInterval()` and `clear_canvas()` - rectangle is drown. Problem seems to be in `clear_canvas()`. I got that code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6722031/458610).

At the moment it just shows blank page. In my opinion, it should draw, clear, draw, clear...

I added`console.log()` for debugging; it's called! No errors or whatever are thrown in Chrome 14 (on Fedora 15, if that matters). Everything seems to be okay; unfortunately, it isn't!

I putted code on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYve5/) so you, guys, can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is is that it is clearing the rectangle the moment it is drawn.

You'll need to make the function alternate between drawing and clearing in order to notice anything.

```
var draw = false;
$(function() {

    setInterval(function() {

        console.log('called');
        if(draw)
                draw_rectange();
        else
                clear_canvas();

        draw = !draw;

    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: Shame on me for not understanding this myself. :(

Comment: You aren't the first one... how do you think I knew that was the problem? :P

Answer (score 0):

Hate to do this guys but its a simple matter of order of operations. clear the canvas before you draw to it, not after.

switch

```
draw_rectange();
clear_canvas();
```

to

```
clear_canvas();
draw_rectange();
```

result:
http://jsfiddle.net/pYve5/4/