# HTML image slideshow gallery stops working after few hours in Safari on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, memory, safari

I've created a web application which displays photos from my Plex server with a fading animation and a current date. Very simple. I am launching it on iPad 2 (iOS 8.4). After few hours of working, the application stops displaying the photos (it looks like an image was not available). I've tried debugging it in safari in macOS, but I was unable to find any error message.

At first I thought that it could be a memory leak:

http://www.fngtps.com/2010/mobile-safari-image-resource-limit-workaround/

[Rapidly updating image with Data URI causes caching, memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913765/rapidly-updating-image-with-data-uri-causes-caching-memory-leak/9927804#9927804)

but my solution: https://github.com/carbolymer/plex-photo-frame/commit/b2b345f14ef8b82fd518dea6969d4cc6d24f6a5c
did not solve the problem (taken from the fngtps.com).

The whole code of the application is available at:

https://github.com/carbolymer/plex-photo-frame/tree/b2b345f14ef8b82fd518dea6969d4cc6d24f6a5c/src

What is going on there?

Comment: Does the iPad ever go to sleep during your tests? Once the screen is locked, after a few minutes, javascript execution of intervals is halted. You can't rely on an interval timer in a mobile device to keep running while the device is asleep

Comment: @JoelCDoyle no, the device is on all the time i.e. not locked