# Draw bitmap data on html5 canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I am receiving base64 encoded bitmap data through sockets, I decoding this data using atob and now have the bitmap data ready to be drawn on an HTML5 canvas.

I was reading this post

[Data URI leak in Safari (was: Memory Leak with HTML5 canvas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538917/data-uri-leak-in-safari-was-memory-leak-with-html5-canvas)

and although I am able to draw my bitmap data on the canvas using context.drawImage(..) I am looking for a different approach, due to memory leaks when alling drawImage too many times.

This post

[Data URI leak in Safari (was: Memory Leak with HTML5 canvas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538917/data-uri-leak-in-safari-was-memory-leak-with-html5-canvas)

refers to "creating a pixel data array and writing it to the canvas with putImageData" however there is no code to support this.

How can I create a pixel data array from my bitmap data ?

Basically I want to draw my bitmap data on the canvas, by using putImageData.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be this you would found useful. [Link](https://gist.github.com/616240).
If this is not what you were looking for then elaborate a little more about your query,
i will surely try to help.