# clearing the canvas for reloading image?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, kineticjs

What am I doing wrong here??

I am writing an image to canvs using html5 image tag.
what i want it to replace the last image onclick of the new image..
I am able to load image but on click of next image it overlaps the last loaded image..
Here is the code..
I'm trying to use clearRect() function

```
           function drawImage(imageObj){

            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage("container", 578, 500);
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var x = stage.width / 2 - 200 / 2;
            var y = stage.height / 2 - 137 / 2;
            var width = 200;
            var height = 137;

            // darth vader
            var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Shape(function(){
                var context = this.getContext();

                context.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
                context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
                // draw invisible detectable path for image
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(x, y, width, height);
                context.closePath(); 


          });
```

Comment: have u tried canvas.width = canvas.width; 
????

Comment: Did try this..its not working..and canvas.width=canvas.width will clear the whole canvas..I just want a section to be removed..so used context.clearRect(x,y,width,height) but it's also not working here.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing).

```
canvas.width = canvas.width;
```

should clear your canvas.

Comment: Did try this..its not working..and canvas.width=canvas.width will clear the whole canvas..I just want a section to be removed..so used context.clearRect(x,y,width,height) but it's also not working here

Comment: Did you read the second answer of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing) ? Try to save and restore the context when you're done cleaning with clearRect().

Comment: Hey I got it already..My kinetic.js file was outdated...so had to update it and the clear canvas feature was added to it..Thanks anyways..:)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function that I created

Call it this way -- `clearCanvasGrid(/id of the canvas/)`

```
function clearCanvasGrid(canvasname){
            var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasname); //because we are looping //each location has its own canvas ID
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            //context.beginPath();

            // Store the current transformation matrix
            context.save();

            // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
            context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            // Restore the transform
            context.restore(); //CLEARS THE SPECIFIC CANVAS COMPLETELY FOR NEW DRAWING

        }
```