# HTML5 canvas with dynamic user input

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I will start off by admitting I have never used canvas before so I don't know if this is possible but I can't seem to find the solution.

I am trying to create a canvas that draws a simple regular polygon shape (all sides are equal) in canvas based on the number of sides and size of the polygon that the user inputs most likely in HTML/PHP form. Nothing is actually saved to a server or database, just used for the one drawing.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3):

You should use a JavaScript library to make it easier to draw on the canvas.

Here's a really good demo of the functionality that you're looking for:

http://fabricjs.com/

And the the library is Fabric.js, which you can download here: http://fabricjs.com/

Comment: Looking at the demo, that is exactly what I am looking for!  Thank you for such a quick response. I will try it tomorrow when I get on my computer

Answer (score 1):

I looked up on google and there was an interesting [tutorial/code](http://www.scienceprimer.com/drawing-regular-polygons-javascript-canvas) which draws a regular polygon with n-sides & size. So I thought of making a function out of it, one of the technical problems I encountered is that when the canvas is drawed and I click to draw another canvas, the second canvas is "overwritten" on the first one. Luckily someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing) solved this problem by clearing the canvas.

So here's my code, you may change it to your needs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Regular Polygon</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="regular_polygon" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

  <p>Polygon drawer:</p>
  <p>Number of sides <input type="text" id="nSides"></p>
  <p>Size <input type="text" id="size"></p>
  <p>Color <input type="text" id="color"></p>
  <p>Width <input type="text" id="width"></p>
  <button id="draw">Draw!</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function polygon (element_id, nSides, psize, pcolor, pwidth) {
      var c = document.getElementById(element_id);
      c.width = c.width;
      var cxt = c.getContext("2d");
      var numberOfSides = nSides,
          size = psize,
          Xcenter = c.width/2,
          Ycenter = c.height/2;

      cxt.beginPath();
      cxt.moveTo (Xcenter +  size * Math.cos(0), Ycenter +  size *  Math.sin(0));

      for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfSides;i += 1) {
        cxt.lineTo (
          Xcenter + size * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides),
          Ycenter + size * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / numberOfSides)
        );
      }

      cxt.strokeStyle = pcolor;
      cxt.lineWidth = pwidth;
      cxt.stroke();
    }

    (function () {
      polygon("regular_polygon", 3, 40, "#000000", 2);
      document.querySelector('#draw').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var nSides = document.querySelector('#nSides'),
            size = document.querySelector('#size'),
            color = document.querySelector('#color'),
            width = document.querySelector('#width');

        polygon("regular_polygon", nSides.value, size.value, color.value, width.value);
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried implementing this script as I liked how it did not require an external javascript file, and I did not need to worry about the extra frills that I did not need in fabricjs, but when I tried adding a circle (arc) to the script, I am now getting a blank canvas.  Any suggestions please?  Here is my modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/campsoup1988/VGfcz/

Comment: I also meant to ask if it is possible to submit the form with just pressing enter when one of the input fields have focus (like in a html/php form)

Comment: I have not included the polygon working yet, but I manged to get the circle working (and simplified a bit with this script)

http://jsfiddle.net/campsoup1988/TeGGx/89/

Comment: @CampSoup1988 i don't get it, you asked specifically for a `regular polygon` and now you're asking for some circle stuff, btw circles don't have SIDES so i don't know why you did add that to your last fiddle ... And there seems something wrong, when you draw for the second time it overwrites the last draw (it doesn't refresh before drawing), so here the fix of it : http://jsfiddle.net/QCUYB/
. THAT external JS you were talking about is jQuery and you can download it for free from jquery.com, there are a lot of tutorials to achieve something like "on focus" etc... Have fun !

Comment: I did not ask for a circle originally because it did not seem hard to do.  I plan on putting the polygon inside of the circle.  I have use jQuery a few times in the past, mostly for form validation.

Comment: So is there something else you want to ask ? If not can you validate this answer :)

Comment: @CampSoup1988 btw here is the fix for your first fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9WqV3/ , you mistyped/copied cxt with ctx ...

Comment: I am still trying to get both the circle and the polygon drawn at the same time.  I cant seem to draw a circle in your script and I cant draw a polygon in mine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13261/discussion-between-hamza-dzcyberdev-and-campsoup1988)