# Get List of DIV below mouse pointer (mouseup event)

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, html5-canvas

I am newbee to JQUERY, I have placed Few DIV elements under a "CANVAS" element. When you click on the DIV element, line drawing will start. When i release the mouse in another DIV it will stop (Line will be drawn b/w those DIV elements). Now i would like to add, If i release the mouse outside the DIV it should clear the drawing. I am not able to figure out the correct to way to catch this event to clear the drawing. Please help me.

HTML Element Structure

```
 <div id="content">
    <div id="draganddrop" >
        <div id="drag_1" class="hitbox"></div>
        <div id="drag_2" class="hitbox"></div>
        <div id="drop_1" class="hitbox">
        <div id="drop_2" class="hitbox">
    </div>
    <canvas id="linedrawing" style="pointer-events:none" class="border"></canvas>
</div>
```

Click Events

```
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $("#drag_1").mousedown(startDrawing);
        $("#drag_2").mousedown(startDrawing);

        $("#drop_1").mousedown(startDrawing);
        $("#drop_2").mousedown(startDrawing);

        $("#draganddrop").mousemove(updateDrawing);
        $("#draganddrop").mouseup(finishDrawing);
    });
</script>
```

If the user release mouse outside "drag_1, drag_2, drop_1, drop_2" i want to clear the drawing. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Bind the [clear method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/) to the body:

```
<script>
    $(function() { 
        $("#drag_1").mousedown(startDrawing);
        $("#drag_2").mousedown(startDrawing);

        $("#drop_1").mousedown(startDrawing);
        $("#drop_2").mousedown(startDrawing);

        $("#draganddrop").mousemove(updateDrawing);
        $("#draganddrop").mouseup(finishDrawing);
        $("body").mouseup(clearDrawing);
    });
</script>
```