# moving object on transparent canvas leaving smear

Tags: javascript, canvas, paint

Why is it that when an object is moved on a keypress event with WASD, if it is on a transparent canvas a black trail follows the images as it moves?

Is there a way to get rid of this paintbush effect? I have a background underneath but it is on a separate canvas. The transparent canvas ontop is supposed to be for the moving WASD character only but the trail it leaves on its transparent canvas is obviously also over the canvas underneath. :*(

Comment: Clear the canvas on every step?

Comment: What you paint on canvas *stays there* just like... a canvas!. Canvas isn't not painting the next frame on a new frame. You must clear the canvas for the next draw.

Comment: if I clear the canvas using rect it will no longer be transparent though? How else can I clear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear the canvas for redrawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: no relation. those solutions make the canvas not transparent. making the canvas full of white pixels does not help here.

Comment: I apologize I was wrong clear rect does let the canvas underneath shows. Really strange that it is called "clearrect" i guess...