# Clearing responsive canvas with lines don't work in IE10

Tags: html, canvas, resize

The code below is an example found on the web, there's plenty of examples like that, but never with lines... 
So I added a line to that code (with BeginPath of course).
When resizing the window, the line is not cleared correctly in IE10. It works great with Chrome and Firefox.

Could you correct my mistake or help me to find a workaround if it's a bug ?

Thanks for your answers.
Olivier.

[EDIT : Image of the problem](http://www.olivierraclet.fr/forums/bug-canvas-lines.jpg)

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){

//Get the canvas & context
var c = $('#respondCanvas');
var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
var container = $(c).parent();

    //Run function when browser  resize
    $(window).resize( respondCanvas );

    function respondCanvas(){
        c.attr('width', $(container).width() ); //max width
        c.attr('height', $(container).height() ); //max height

        //Redraw & reposition content
        var x = c.width();
        var y = c.height();             
        ct.font = "20px Calibri";

        ct.fillStyle = "#D0DDDD"; //black
        ct.fillRect( 0, 0, x, y); //fill the canvas

        var resizeText = "Canvas width: "+c.width()+"px";
        ct.textAlign = "center";
        ct.fillStyle = "#333333"; //white
        ct.fillText(resizeText, (x/2), (y/2) );

        //Draw a line
        ct.beginPath;
        ct.moveTo(0,0);
        ct.lineTo(ct.canvas.width/2,100);
        ct.strokeStyle = "#AAAAAA";
        ct.closePath();
        ct.stroke();                
    }
    //Initial call
    respondCanvas();
});
</script>
<style>
html, body{ margin:0px; padding:0px; }
body{ display:block; width:100%; height:100%; }
#main{ display:block; width:80%; padding:50px 10%; height:300px; }
</style>

<body>
<div id="main" role="main">
    <canvas id="respondCanvas" width="100" height="100">
        <!-- Provide fallback -->
    </canvas>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a bug in IE10. However instead of relying on it being cleared by re-sizing try clearing it activity like described by the second answer in this thread: [How to clear the canvas for redrawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Hope that helps.