# Canvas: returning to state before drawing

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, web, drawimage

Is it possible to go back after I use `drawImage`?

Example:

I draw an image and them overdraw another. I want to delete the first image and, on the clear surface, draw a new image.

Is it possible?

Comment: I do not understand...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear the canvas for redrawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: Sure...You can clear your canvas for the new image like this:  context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height) where canvas is a reference to your html canvas element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to undo drawImage changes, you must save canvas data before doing drawImage like:

```
tmp = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, with, height);
//do changes here
canvas.getContext("2d").putImageData(tmp , 0, 0);
//here changes will be lost
```

this is unswer to the title, question content was not clear for me