# Preventing jQuery mobile from reinitializing pages when moving between tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, canvas, initialization, html5-canvas

In my mobile website, I have a couple of pages, with a tab navbar at the bottom letting users navigate between them. On one of the pages I have a canvas the users can draw on. Problem is, every time I move to one page and then back to the canvas page, I see the old drawing for a second, but then it is cleared away.

I think this is caused because of the page re-initializing everytime I enter it, so how may that be prevented?

I have already tried caching the pages, whoch didnt seem to help... Any other ideas?

Comment: how about resetting the canvas on [pagebeforeshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/). Sounds to me like you start on a page with the canvas, then go somewhere else (with your canvas page still being in the DOM), then when you go back your first canvas page is shown "as-is" before you update it?

Comment: yes. is there a way to prevent it from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You should clear the canvas on jQuery mobile [pagebeforeshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/).

The first page the user navigates to will always stay in the DOM, so if that page contains a canvas and the user goes to another page and back, you will have to reset the canvas element manually.

This question shows how to reset the canvas - [how to clear canvas for redraw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing).

So your code should look something like this:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "div.id_or_class_of_page(s)_with_canvas", function () {
    ctx = _your_canvavs_element;

    ctx.save();
    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Restore the transform
    ctx.restore();
});
```

Not sure about the canvas code.

Comment: So should I just take an image of the canvas, and then restore it once the user navigates back to the page?