# Canvas - delete drawimages

Tags: image, canvas

In my canvas adds 2 images. 1 images is "background canvas". 2 image is cut from 1 image and add to background.

Add background (1 images):

```
img.onload = function() {
     img2= new Image();
     img2.src=e.target.result;
     canvas.width  = this.width;
     canvas.height = this.height;  
     context.drawImage(img2,0,0);                              
}
```

Add 2 images:

```
var c=document.getElementById('obrazek');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src =$('#blur').getCanvasImage();
img1.onload = function(){
    ctx.translate(xStart,yStart);  
    ctx.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, d, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.drawImage(img1,-xStart,-yStart);
}
```

I need clean background.  I want delete 2 image and load again background.

My clean:

```
context.drawImage(img2,0,0);
```

After cleaning background, I see:

[image]

2 image is wrong removed, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your clipping region or else all further draws will be restricted to your circle.

- save the unclipped context
- do your clipped drawing
- restore the context to its unclipped state

Like this:

```
function drawAll(backgroundImage,topImage,xStart,yStart,d){

      // clear the whole canvas of all images

      ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);

      // save the unclipped context

      ctx.save()

      // draw the background image (not clipped)

      ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0);

      // create a clipping circle

      ctx.arc(xStart,yStart,d,0,Math.PI*2);
      ctx.clip();

      // draw the top image restricted to the clipping circle

      ctx.drawImage(topImage,xStart-topImage.width/2,yStart-topImage.height/2);

      // restore the context (clears the clipping circle)

      ctx.restore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need to clear your context before you redraw

See related issue:

[How to clear the canvas for redrawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: I tested it. Doesn't work. In my opinion removed only background and 1/4 circle.

Comment: Did you try getting a new context

    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

Comment: Yes. See screenshot. Clean is only 1/4 circle (at the bottom-right) and next is cut  1 image... When i do: ctx.clearRect, it doesn't help. I want delete circle and load again background.

Answer (score 0):

This too work:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0, c.width, c.height); 
var w = c.width;
c.width = 1;
c.width = w;
context.clearRect ( 0 , 0 , canvas.width , canvas.height );
context.drawImage(img2,0,0);
```