# Canvas and color swapping

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm swapping 2 circles color but when I swap them based on a timer the strokes do not swap even though I don't even have a stroke applied to them:

Image reference:
[image: After and Before]

And code for reference:
[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qzz1mmhq/2/)

```
function sw(obj1, obj2){
  obj1.color = [obj2.color, obj2.color = obj1.color][0];
  console.log("Changed");
  render();
}

function render(){
  _dots[0].draw();
  _dots[1].draw();
}

render();   

setTimeout(function(){
 sw( _dots[0] ,  _dots[1] )
},1000 )
```

Comment: A wild guess is that you used `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: Same effect with setInterval

Comment: you mean the color is bleeding out? That's anti aliasing.

Comment: (Use `setInterval(…, 50)` for party mode :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The antialiased edges are drawing over the last frame rendered, making the edges appear purple. [Clear the canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing) before drawing the next frame.