# Moving circle in a straight line from left to the right of canvas

Tags: javascript, html

I am here trying to draw a moving circle in a straight line with this code. But im wrong to put a syntax. Help me to correct this code.

```
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw_circle (circleX, circleY, radius, fill) { 
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 300);

    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.strokeRect(5, 5, 790, 290);

    var speed = 5

    context.fillStyle = fill;
    context.arc(circleX, circleY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    context.fill();
}

setInterval(draw_circle(100,100, 30 , "cyan"), 33);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to clear your canvas (using [`canvas.width = canvas.width`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing) or [`clearRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect))

Note that you will have to add `context.beginPath()` in order to have `clearRect()` do his job.

Once done you just have to increment the x position of your arc.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function draw_circle (circleX, circleY, radius, fill) { 
    //clear the canvas
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 300);

    context.strokeStyle = "red";
    context.strokeRect(5, 5, 790, 290);
    var speed = 5;
    //just a loop if you don't want it simply use `i+=speed;`
    (i>canvas.width+radius)?i=(radius*-2):i+=speed;
    context.fillStyle = fill;
    context.arc(circleX, circleY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    context.fill();
}

var i=0;

setInterval(function(){draw_circle(i,100, 30 , "cyan")}, 33);
```

```html
<canvas id = "myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: And to bouce it left to right do something like this http://jsfiddle.net/c4vxb9tx/ (based on the answer, you can replace vectorx with the speed if you want)

Comment: And dwana , i have a question. Is it possible to use a parameter in your code? I want to learn more how to put a parameter in my code :)