# Javascript -->moving character Issue

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>TileMap2</title>
  <style>
    #canvas {
      outline: 3px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="1000"></canvas>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      drawMap();
    }

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = "1000";
    canvas.height = "400";

    var xpos = 0;
    var ypos = 0;
    var grass = new Image();
    var water = new Image();
    var dirt = new Image();
    var mario = new Image();

    mario.src = 'Mario.png';
    grass.src = 'grass1.jpg';
    water.src = 'water.jpg';
    dirt.src = 'dirt.jpg';

    var map = [
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

    ];

    function drawMap() {
      for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {

          if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 0) {
            context.drawImage(grass, xpos, ypos);
          }

          if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 1) {
            context.drawImage(dirt, xpos, ypos)
          };
          if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 2) {
            context.drawImage(water, xpos, ypos);
          }
          xpos += 100;
        }
        xpos = 0;
        ypos += 100;
      }
      xpos = 0;
      ypos = 0;
      context.drawImage(mario, xpos, ypos, 50, 50);
    }

    function move(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        xpos += 50;
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        xpos -= 50;
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        ypos -= 50;
      }
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        ypos += 50;
      }

      canvas.width = canvas.width;
      context.drawImage(mario, xpos, ypos, 50, 50);

    }
    document.onkeydown = move;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when i am pressing the arrow keys mario moves but the grass,dirt,water images disapper and the only thing remaining is mario moving in a canvas. That problem is solved if i type in the move function canvas.width=canvas.width but then mario moves leaving highlights of his previous positions on the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

To stop your Mario image from leaving streaks, you can clear your canvas each time you change Mario's position, and redraw the map (with Mario on top).

But right now, your `drawMap()` function modifies the global x- and y-coordinates when it draws the map, which makes it impossible to track Mario's position if we try to call `drawMap()` every time. So it needs to be modified first, to use just some temporary local variables:

```
function drawMap() {
  var localX = 0;
  var localY = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++) {

      if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 0) {
        context.drawImage(grass, localX, localY);
      }

      if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 1) {
        context.drawImage(dirt, localX, localY)
      };
      if (parseInt(map[i][j]) == 2) {
        context.drawImage(water, localX, localY);
      }
      localX += 100;
    }
    localX = 0;
    localY += 100;
  }
}
```

Now, we can draw the map without overwriting Mario's position. Note that I pulled out the drawing of Mario from this function, so the other parts of your code that need to change are:

```
window.onload = function() {
  drawMap();
  context.drawImage(mario, xpos, ypos, 50, 50);
}
```

And, change your current `move()` function to:

```
function move(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    xpos += 50;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    xpos -= 50;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    ypos -= 50;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    ypos += 50;
  }

  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawMap();
  context.drawImage(mario, xpos, ypos, 50, 50);
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8ba0nej/) to demonstrate. The reason I removed `canvas.width = canvas.width` for clearing the canvas is due to the problems with this method cited in [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately it doesnt't work it just moves the horizantal  and the vertical  line of pictures from mario's starting coordinates ...                                                                                    function move(e){
  //[...]

 context.drawImage(mario,xpos,ypos,50,50);
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  drawMap();  }

Comment: Actually i get the same result as                                                  function move(e){//[....]                                                   canvas.width=canvas.width;
 context.drawImage(mario,xpos,ypos,50,50);
 drawMap();
 }

Comment: All right, I see. Let me make an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank you vey much my problem is solved now !!!

Comment: @NickGreen Great, glad I could help you out! Be sure to accept the answer if it gave you the working solution - that way, others can know that your question has been answered.

Comment: I have a question though. Could you please explain why you put two different variables in the draw map function ?

Comment: @NickGreen Because it looked like you were using the `xpos` and `ypos` variables to store Mario's position, since those were the reference coordinates you were using to draw Mario. However, your original `drawMap()` function modified those two variables when it was drawing your map elements, ultimately resetting them back to 0. As a result, every time `drawMap()` was called, Mario's position would get overwritten. That was why I had the function use a couple local variables instead, so the global ones (containing Mario's position) would be preserved.