# HTML canvas spotlight effect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Let's say I have the following code.

```js
// Find out window height and width
wwidth = $(window).width();
wheight = $(window).height();

// Place Canvas over current Window 
$("body").append($("<canvas id='test' style='position:absolute; top:0; left:0;'></canvas>"));
var context = document.getElementById("test").getContext("2d");
context.canvas.width = wwidth;
context.canvas.height = wheight;

// Paint the canvas black.
context.fillStyle = '#000';
context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

// On Mousemove, create "Flashlight" around the mouse, to see through the canvas
$(window).mousemove(function(event){
  x = event.pageX;
  y = event.pageY;
  radius = 50;
  context = document.getElementById("test").getContext("2d");

  // Paint the canvas black.  Instead it will draw it white?!
  //context.fillStyle = '#000';
  //context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  //context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

  context.beginPath();
  radialGradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 1, x, y, radius);
  radialGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
  radialGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

  context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

  context.fillStyle = radialGradient;
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
  context.fill();
  context.closePath();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Test</div>
```

which generates the following effect on mousemove:

[image: Here you can see the above scripted effect]

How do I refill the canvas with black before the spotlight is drawn? I have already tried with what is in the commented-out code block, but it paints everything white.

EDIT: I dont want this effect over an image. Instead i would like to place the Canvas over the whole Webpage. ALso I want the Canvas to be always black and the mouse generates a Spotlight over its position, to see what is under the Canvas just as u can see in the picture, or in the Snippet where a div was placed in an empty html page with "Test" in it.

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing?

Comment: Several problems here. We cannot reproduce your example, for example `giveCanvasContext` isn't a function naively. Note for filling the canvas with a black color you don't need `beginPath` or `endPath`.

Comment: @ ci_ yes i did, but it seems like the canvas will be drawn white instead of filled up with black again..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can use compositing to create your flashlight effect:**

- Clear the canvas
- Create a radial gradient to use as a reveal.
- Fill the radial gradient.
- Use `source-atop` compositing to draw the background image. The image will display only inside the radial gradient.
- Use `destination-over` compositing to fill the canvas with black. The black will fill "behind" the existing radial-gradient-image.

[image][image]

**Here's example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

var radius=30;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
  draw(150,150,30);
}
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/annotateMe.jpg'


function draw(cx,cy,radius){
  ctx.save();
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  var radialGradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(cx, cy, 1, cx, cy, radius);
  radialGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
  radialGradient.addColorStop(.65, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
  radialGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle=radialGradient;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-atop';
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.restore();
}


function handleMouseMove(e){

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  draw(mouseX,mouseY,30);

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move mouse to reveal image with "flashlight"</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**If your spotlight radius will never change, here's a much faster method:**

The speed is gained by caching the spotlight to a second canvas and then...

1. Draw the image on the canvas.
2. Draw the spotlight on the canvas.
3. Use `fillRect` to black out the 4 rectangles outside the spotlight.

Example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var radius=50;

var cover=document.createElement('canvas');
var cctx=cover.getContext('2d');
var size=radius*2+10;
cover.width=size;
cover.height=size;
cctx.fillRect(0,0,size,size);
var radialGradient = cctx.createRadialGradient(size/2, size/2, 1, size/2, size/2, radius);
radialGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
radialGradient.addColorStop(.65, 'rgba(0,0,0,1)');
radialGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
cctx.beginPath();
cctx.arc(size/2,size/2,size/2,0,Math.PI*2);
cctx.fillStyle=radialGradient;
cctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';
cctx.fill();

var img=new Image();
img.onload=function(){
  $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,ch);
}
img.src='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/annotateMe.jpg'


function drawCover(cx,cy){
  var s=size/2;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
  ctx.drawImage(cover,cx-size/2,cy-size/2);
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cx-s,ch);
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,cw,cy-s);
  ctx.fillRect(cx+s,0,cw-cx,ch);
  ctx.fillRect(0,cy+s,cw,ch-cy);
}

function handleMouseMove(e){

  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  drawCover(mouseX,mouseY);
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move mouse to reveal image with "flashlight"</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the spotlight effect by positioning a canvas directly over the image. Make the canvas the same size as the image and set the compositing operation to `xor` so that two black pixels drawn in the same place cancel each other out.

```
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
```

Now you can paint the canvas black and fill a black circle around the mouse cursor. The result is a hole in the black surface, showing the image underneath.

```
// Paint the canvas black.
context.fillStyle = '#000';
context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
// Paint a black circle around x, y.
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, spotlightRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.fillStyle = '#000';
context.fill();
// With xor compositing, the result is a circular hole.
```

To make a spotlight with blurry edges, define a radial gradient centered on the mouse position and fill a square around it.

```
var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, spotlightRadius);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)');
gradient.addColorStop(0.9, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
context.fillStyle = gradient;
context.fillRect(x - spotlightRadius, y - spotlightRadius,
                 2 * spotlightRadius, 2 * spotlightRadius);
```

The following snippet demonstrates both approaches using pure JavaScript. To change from a crisp-edged spotlight to a blurry-edged spotlight, click on the checkbox above the image.

```js
function getOffset(element, ancestor) {
  var left = 0,
      top = 0;
  while (element != ancestor) {
    left += element.offsetLeft;
    top += element.offsetTop;
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  return { left: left, top: top };
}

function getMousePosition(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.pageX !== undefined) {
    return { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY };
  }
  return {
    x: event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    y: event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
        document.documentElement.scrollTop
  };
}

window.onload = function () {
  var spotlightRadius = 60,
      container = document.getElementById('container'),
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
      image = container.getElementsByTagName('img')[0],
      width = canvas.width = image.width,
      height = canvas.height = image.height,
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
  container.insertBefore(canvas, image.nextSibling);
  container.style.width = width + 'px';
  container.style.height = height + 'px';
  var offset = getOffset(canvas, document.body);
      clear = function () {
        context.fillStyle = '#000';
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
      };
  clear();
  image.style.visibility = 'visible';
  canvas.onmouseout = clear;
  canvas.onmouseover = canvas.onmousemove = function (event) {
    var mouse = getMousePosition(event),
        x = mouse.x - offset.left,
        y = mouse.y - offset.top;
    clear();
    if (document.getElementById('blurry').checked) {
      var gradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 0, x, y, spotlightRadius);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)');
      gradient.addColorStop(0.875, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)');
      gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)');
      context.fillStyle = gradient;
      context.fillRect(x - spotlightRadius, y - spotlightRadius,
                       2 * spotlightRadius, 2 * spotlightRadius);
    } else {
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, spotlightRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.fillStyle = '#000';
      context.fill();
    }
  };
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.control {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#container img, #container canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#container img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
#container canvas {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="control">
  <input type="checkbox" id="blurry" /> blurry edges
</p>

<div id="container">
  <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/annotateMe.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me:

```
x = event.pageX;
y = event.pageY;
radius = 10;
context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

context.beginPath();
var radialGradient= context.createRadialGradient(x,y,1,x,y,radius);
radialGradient.addColorStop(0,"rgba(255,255,255,1");
radialGradient.addColorStop(1,"rgba(0,0,0,1)");
//context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
context.fillStyle = radialGradient; 
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

it seems that this line was messing it `context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";`

there were also pointless lines in your code like beginnig path before filling rect and fill() function after filling path

Comment: This code enables the spotlight effect yes, but it wont actually show whats under the canvas which is what i want

Comment: hi I have a similar issue where i have a canvas over which some elements are there and I want to keep them hidden just like black screen and a circular spotlight around the mouse pointer so that wherever I move the mouse the things become visible. The thing is that most of these codes work on image as background but I dont have a image background I have a canvas and I want to have this effect on it. Can u help ?