# Canvas flashlight effect with layered images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am trying to do an image effect very similar to the one on [Canvas flashlight effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47580694/canvas-flashlight-effect) however, instead of the frontlayer just being a color i would like it to be an image.
Grabbing the code @Kaiido answered I've try to changed but when I put the a pattern inside the event it gives me an error.

```js
// Find out window height and width
wwidth = $(window).width();
wheight = $(window).height();

// Place Canvas over current Window 
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas"),
context = ctx.getContext('2d'),
img = new Image;
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/bnAEEXq.jpg";

img.onload = function(){
  context.canvas.width = wwidth;
  context.canvas.height = wheight;

  // Paint the canvas black.
  context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

  // On Mousemove, create "Flashlight" around the mouse, to see through the canvas
  $(window).mousemove(function(event){
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    radius = 100;
    context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    // first reset the gCO
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    // Paint the canvas with the initial image.
    // context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat");
    context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    radialGradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 1, x, y, 100);
    radialGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
    radialGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

    context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

    context.fillStyle = radialGradient;
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
     }
      #canvas {
        position:fixed; 
        top:0; 
        left:0;
        background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/calgary-bridge-1943.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your error? I don't see any error in my console ...And the effect seems to work in the snippet

Comment: // context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat"); if you uncoment this line (instead of context.fillStyle = "#ffffff" so that we can have an image instead of a color) it will give the error: "Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `img` you assigned earlier rather than `this` when you call `context.createPattern`.

```js
// Find out window height and width
wwidth = $(window).width();
wheight = $(window).height();

// Place Canvas over current Window 
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas"),
context = ctx.getContext('2d'),
img = new Image;
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/bnAEEXq.jpg";

img.onload = function(){
  context.canvas.width = wwidth;
  context.canvas.height = wheight;

  // Paint the canvas black.
  context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

  // On Mousemove, create "Flashlight" around the mouse, to see through the canvas
  $(window).mousemove(function(event){
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    radius = 100;
    context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    // first reset the gCO
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    // Paint the canvas with the initial image.
    context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(img, "no-repeat");
    //context.fillStyle = "#ffffff88";
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    radialGradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 1, x, y, 100);
    radialGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
    radialGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

    context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

    context.fillStyle = radialGradient;
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
     }
      #canvas {
        position:fixed; 
        top:0; 
        left:0;
        background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/calgary-bridge-1943.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you could also use the newish arrow functions to preserve your context for the keyword `this`:

```js
// Find out window height and width
wwidth = $(window).width();
wheight = $(window).height();

// Place Canvas over current Window 
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas"),
context = ctx.getContext('2d'),
img = new Image;
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/bnAEEXq.jpg";

img.onload = function(){
  context.canvas.width = wwidth;
  context.canvas.height = wheight;

  // Paint the canvas black.
  context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
  context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

  // On Mousemove, create "Flashlight" around the mouse, to see through the canvas
  $(window).mousemove((event) => {
    x = event.clientX;
    y = event.clientY;
    radius = 100;
    context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    // first reset the gCO
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    // Paint the canvas with the initial image.
    context.fillStyle = context.createPattern(this, "no-repeat");
    //context.fillStyle = "#ffffff88";
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
    context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    radialGradient = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 1, x, y, 100);
    radialGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
    radialGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

    context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

    context.fillStyle = radialGradient;
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, false);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
     }
      #canvas {
        position:fixed; 
        top:0; 
        left:0;
        background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/calgary-bridge-1943.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
      }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you