# how to remove the previous canvas shape when i call the canvas again?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I make canvas to draw a square with random size , when I press **Next** button
I call the `canvasarea()` function that draws a square with the random size that he get,but I faced a problem with that, because the previous square still in the canvas , and the previous of previous , and so on .
what is the solution?

```
function canvasarea(){

var canvas = document.getElementById('square');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.beginPath();
var Size=getSize();

context.rect(10,10, 5*Size, 5*Size);
context.fillStyle = 'red';
context.fill();
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';

context.stroke();


        }

function getSize(){
var min = 30;
var max = 40;
var size = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
document.getElementById("sideSize").innerHTML=size;
return size;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear the canvas for redrawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister  `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`  **I tried it , but it remove the canvas at all , and when I call `canvasarea()` it doesn't draw any more**

Comment: Where in your code did you try it? Also, what do you mean by "it remove the canvas at all"?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I need to draw again when I recall the function ,

Comment: I put `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` at the begining of `cnavasarea()` it didn't work , I tried to put it at the last thing in `canvasarea()` and it didn't work.
i mean in _it remove the canvas at all_  that I can't draw anything after recall the `canvasarea()` , when I used `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` @MaximillianLaumeister

Answer (score 1):

Before you draw the shape, clear the canvas using this method:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Here is the the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) for `CanvasRenderingContext2D.clearRect()`

Answer (score 0):

I make 2 function ,the first one is to clear the canvas and the second one to redraw the canvas with the same properties of the original canvas but with different size

```
  function canvasarea(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('square');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.beginPath();
  var Size=getSize();
  context.rect(10,10, 5*Size, 5*Size);
  context.fillStyle = 'red';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth =7;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  clear(canvas);
  redraw();

        }

 function clear(a){
 a.getContext('2d').clearRect(0,0,a.width,a.height);
 }

 function redraw(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById('square');
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 context.beginPath();
 var Size=getSize(); 
 context.rect(10,10, 5*Size, 5*Size);
 context.fillStyle = 'red';
 context.fill();
 context.lineWidth = 7;
 context.strokeStyle = 'black';


      }
```