# Cross-hair Cursor HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I'm making a basic website for my engineering company and would like to include a full page cross-hair like cursor. Is there any way to include this in my site? Here's an example of this cursor: (I can't include the picture in the post because of lack of reputation.) http://imagebin.ca/v/2GSxt6zx57A5

I would like for this to follow around the page in place of a normal cursor. I can use javascript or CSS if its needed to make this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My HTML and Javascript skills are a little rusty but something like this should do it:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.onmousemove = function (e)
{
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();

    context.moveTo(e.clientX,0);
    context.lineTo(e.clientX, canvas.height);
    context.stroke();

    context.moveTo(0, e.clientY);
    context.lineTo(canvas.width, e.clientY);
    context.stroke();
};

</script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3; cursor : none">
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just came out as a blank box

Comment: Ah yeah, might need some tweaking, like I said, I'm a little rusty. If I get some more time today I'll try make a working version for you. In the meantime you'll have to fiddle with it yourself.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks if you can spare some time for it. I'm not good at coding so i'll have some trouble haha. Thanks

Comment: The solution works for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b4rnq6fe/), although it needed a couple of tweaks: the canvas should be cleared first (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2142549/2482744) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2142549/2482744)) and canvas.{width,height} were mixed up.

Comment: How do you erase the cursor?

Comment: use the style: "cursor : none"

Comment: Added that to the answer too.