# Using jquery, how can I clear items from a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am [using this jquery code](http://iprodev.com/confetti-animation-javascript/) to have falling confetti on a page.  Here [is the demo page](http://codepen.io/iprodev/full/azpWBr/).

It works well and I see I can the start and stop functions to controls the updates from happening but I don't see a "clear()" method that would remove all of the confetti from the canvas.

Here is my html below, I have a background on my canvas and I don't want that to be removed but I simply want a way to clear out all of the confetti from the canvas so I only see the background image.

```
 <canvas style="background-repeat:no-repeat;background-image: url('/Content/Images/myImage.png');" id="confetti" width="1" height="1"></canvas>
```

Comment: Most likely a duplicate of [How to clear the canvas for redrawing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing) and for retrieving the context [MDN: HTMLCanvasElement.getContext()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext#Examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `clear()` yourself:

```
// Somewhere inside this
confetti.Context = function (id) {
  ...
  this.clear = function () {
    this.stop();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  ...
}
```

Then this can be called anywhere else in your code like:

```
confetti.clear();
```