# Remove glow from HTML5 canvas drawings?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

If I draw a green circle on a black background, then draw the same circle in black, a green shadow/glow is left behind. The circle is not actually erased.

How do I make it purely black again and remove the glow?

I've tried `context.shadowColor = "transparent";`

Here is a snippet:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x-1, y-2, 2, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
//context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
//context.stroke();
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x-1, y-2, 2, 0, 2*Math.PI);
context.fillStyle = "#000000";
//context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
//context.stroke();
context.fill();
```

Here is the full object:

[image]

Comment: [How to clear a canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: @adeneo I've already done that, but I don't want other objects to be deleted too!!

Comment: This is caused by antialiasing, you have to try a different approach, like clearing the whole canvas and redraw your image, or use multiple canvases

Comment: There is not much that can be done. It is the result of antialiasing and how it is converted to the bit depth of the canvas. You can copy parts of the canvas and then draw the saved copies when you need to remove something you have drawn. Or you can just draw everything each time you change what is displayed.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a jsFiddle link?

Comment: @TheMintyMate I think the code I wrote is pretty clear, but I pasted it here: https://jsfiddle.net/9yuts9pc/

Comment: @TheMintyMate did the fiddle help, or?

Comment: Apologies, as there is an answer ticked as correct here, I assumed this question was closed. I did look at your fiddle, only it **doesn't appear** as shown in your image above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to clear the canvas.**

By the looks of the image you gave you are wanting to write a game or an animation of some sort.

The general way games and animations are done are by redrawing the entire game screen every frame. This greatly simplifies the design of the rendering engine. Makes it easy to draw one thing over the other by simply changing the order in which you draw them. To make something vanish just don't render it.

I am assuming you know how to load images

**Clearing the screen**

You have several ways to clear the screen.

```
// assuming ctx is the 2d Context and width and height are the canvas width and height.
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

Or by filling the screen with a rectangle.

```
var backgroundColour = "#000";
ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColour;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

Or use a background image

```
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.src = "backgroundImage URL";
// then wait for image to load.
// then 
ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, width, height);
```

**Drawing sprites**

Now you can draw the graphics. Again there are many ways to do this. One approch is to keep a list of all the objects and draw them all in one go after the screen has cleared.

```
// create or load a game sprite (image)
var gameSprite = new Image();
gameSprite.src = "gameSprite URL";
// create a list of sprites.
var mySprites = [
    {x : 10, y : 10, image : gameSprite}, // sprite 1
    {x : 30, y : 60, image : gameSprite}, // sprite 2
    {x : 70, y : 40, image : gameSprite}  // sprite 3
];

// itterate the list and draw each sprite one at a time.
function renderSprites (spriteList) {
    var i,len,s;
    len = spriteList.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        s = spriteList[i];
        ctx.drawImage(s.image, s.x, s.y);
    }
}
```

**Animating it all**

The last thing is you need to sync it all up with the display hardware so that it runs at the maximum frame rate possible and does not create artifacts such as shearing, or flickering. To do this you use `requestAnimationFrame` which is similar to `setTimeout` but you do not supply the timing the browser takes care of that.

You will need a main loop function that you provide to `requestAnimationFrame` to call when the browser is ready to draw the next frame. In this function you first clear the screen, do the game logic, draw all the sprites, and then request the next frame (though you can request the next frame at any stage within the main loop).

```
function mainLoop(time){   // requestAnimationFrame adds the argument (time). 
                           // This is the time in milliseconds.
    // clear the screen
    ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,width,height);

    // do game logic here

    renderSprites(mySprites); // draw the sprites

    // now request the next frame and do it all again.
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}

// start the animation by requesting the first frame.
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

This will run at 60fps (frames per second) and can easly handle over 100 sprites (on all but the most basic device)