# Bouncing balls drawing inside a canvas, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function refBalls(){
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var circles = [{x:40,y:100,r:20,color:'black',vx:5,vy:10}]
function draw(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circles[0].x, circles[0].y, circles[0].r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    if( (circles[0].x + circles[0].r + circles[0].vx > c.width + c.style.left) || (circles[0].x - circles[0].r + circles[0].vx < c.style.left) ){
        circles[0].vx = -circles[0].vx;
    }
    circles[0].x += circles[0].vx;
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);}
```

I am able to see the ball moving but I'm seeing its previous position. I should be seeing a ball moving, instead I'm seeing a strip like a ball painting on the canvas. Can someone help me? [this is what I'm seeing in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIdbw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to clear your canvas every time you draw the frame.  This is the same way video games render their content onto the screen.

Some examples here:
[How to clear the canvas for redrawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: in the example there's some further reading. but basically use ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); at the beginning of your animation frame