# My Game loop accelerates and character leaves a trail

Tags: javascript, game-loop

The code:

```
// create stuff
var ghObj = {
x : 0,
y : 0
}
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ghost = new Image();
ghost.src = "ghost.png"

//define variables
var ghostMove = function () {
    ghObj.x+=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 - 4))
    console.log(ghObj.x)
    ghObj.y+=(Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 - 4))
}

var ghostCheck = function () {
    if (ghObj.x<0) {
        ghObj.x=0
    }
    if (ghObj.x>390) {
        ghObj.x=390
    }
    if (ghObj.y<0) {
        ghObj.y=0
    }
    if (ghObj.y>390) {
        ghObj.y=390
    }
}

var drawIm = function (sprite, position) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(position.x, position.y);
    ctx.drawImage(sprite, 0, 0, sprite.width, sprite.height, 0, 0, sprite.width, sprite.height);
    ctx.restore();
};

// begin "game" when ghost is loaded
ghost.onload = function() {
    mainLoop()
}

// main loop
    function() {

    ghostMove()

    ghostCheck()

    drawIm(ghost, ghObj)

    setInterval(mainLoop, 1000) 
}
```

sorry if its a bit long.

what's *supposed* to happen is the ghost moves randomly round the screen at a steady rate.
instead, it moves randomly but increasingly quickly and leaves copies of itself everywhere.

Isn't the restore function supposed to clear the screen each time?

have i got the game loop wrong?
thanks in advance.

Comment: No it does not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore

Comment: Use clearRect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing

Comment: I think you should reread the definition of *BASIC*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mainLoop(){
  setInterval(mainLoop,100);
}
```

I think the error is obvious. I recommend to use setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame instead... And this should remove the *duplicates* i think its an optical ilusion
...

Comment: @darkrum because of?

Comment: i tried  setTimeout and clearRect earlier, but must have mispelled something :( lesson learnt: try everything twice