# Why is my object elongating instead of moving?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to coding. And I am new to stack overflow. Please, please fogive me if I am not following any of the myriad of rules users have to follow around here.

I am trying to move an object on an HTML5 canvas using a javasript code. Instead, it keeps seeming to elongate. Do I have to use a clear function of some sort? When I do that, it seems to make the black square (player) disappear instead.

Here is my code. Any advice/suggestions would be helpful.

```js
var c;
var ctx;
var playerPosX = 90;
var playerPosY = 90;

function init(){
  c = document.getElementById("c");
  ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
  setInterval (player, 10);
  }


function player(){
  c=document.getElementById("c");
  ctx= c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.fillStyle='black';
  ctx.fillRect(playerPosX,playerPosY,20,20);
}

init();
function doKeyDown (evt){
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
    case 40:
      playerPosY=playerPosY+1;
      break;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', doKeyDown, true);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: The rules are simple: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to clear be canvas before you draw the player. Otherwise, the newly drawn reactangle will overlap with the old one, which makes it look like it's elongating.

Use [`CanvasRenderingContext2D#clearRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) to clear the canvas:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let playerPosX = 90;
let playerPosY = 90;

function draw () {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  // clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  // draw the background
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
  
  // draw the player
  ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
  ctx.fillRect(playerPosX, playerPosY, 20, 20);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => e.key === 'ArrowDown' && playerPosY++);
```

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

As you can see, I refactored your code a bit, for example using [`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Comment: thank you again for your kind and quick responses. Apologies if this post was inappropriate... please do let me know what I can do to avoid getting down-voted.

Comment: I guess the reason for the downvote was that you didn't include the code in your question. It's easier to help you if you give us a short code snippet and a specific problem. That's what AGE meant with the [mcve]. But don't worry too much, you'll get used to it. StackOverflow has strict rules, but a great community. For a start, you could read [ask] and take the [tour]. I hope my answer helped you.