# How to populate a color dropdown using a javascript array

Tags: javascript, html

I need to populate a dropdown list with an array of color names. Below is the HTML and js codes I have, but when I actually press the drop-down, none of the colors show up and when I click the colors, the color of the canvas does not change. It also needs to have a button that clears the canvas when pressed.
**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Project 3</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Project 3">
<meta name="author" content="Kim Peoples">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="p3.css">
<script src="p3.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="colorDropdown">
        <option>Select a Background Color</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button onclick="clearCanvas">Clear Canvas</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
let selectElement = document.getElementById('#colorDropdown'),
let options = ["BlueViolet", "Crimson", "DarkSalmon", "OliveDrab", "SaddleBrown"];
for (let i < options.length - 1; i = 0; i++) {
    let opt = options[i];
    let optionList = document.createElement("option");
    optionList.textContent = opt;
    optionList.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(optionList)
}
document.getElementById('colorDropdown').onchange = function(){
let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = document.getElementById('colorDropdown').value;

ctx.fill();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a clear function: reference that question.
Small fixes and some comments

```js
// probably should put this into a function so here....
window.onload = function () {
    let selectElement = document.getElementById('colorDropdown'),
      options = ["BlueViolet", "Crimson", "DarkSalmon", "OliveDrab", "SaddleBrown"];
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length - 1; i++) {
      let opt = options[i];
      let optionList = document.createElement("option");
      optionList.textContent = opt;
      optionList.value = opt;
      selectElement.appendChild(optionList)
    }
}
document.getElementById('colorDropdown').onchange = function() {
  let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = document.getElementById('colorDropdown').value;
  ctx.fill();
};
// Leverage another question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2142535/125981
document.getElementById('clearCanvas').onclick =
  function clearCanvas() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.save();
    // Use the identity matrix while clearing the canvas
    context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // Restore the transform
    context.restore();
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <form id="myForm">
    <select id="colorDropdown">
        <option>Select a Background Color</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <button id="clearCanvas">Clear Canvas</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just had some syntax issues. I've copied your code to a JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/wtvkv2t4/1/, and made the following changes:

- Removed the `let` keyword from before the `options` variable name. You've used a comma at the end of the `let selectElement .....` line, so you don't need to define `options` as a `let`, because it already is.
- Changed the order of the parameters in the for loop condition
- Replaced the use of a variable named `select` with the name of the variable that you actually defined, called `selectElement`

Here is the new, working code:

```
let selectElement = document.getElementById('colorDropdown'),
options = ["BlueViolet", "Crimson", "DarkSalmon", "OliveDrab", "SaddleBrown"];

for (let i = 0 ; i < options.length - 1; i++) {
  let opt = options[i];
  let optionList = document.createElement("option");
  optionList.textContent = opt;
  optionList.value = opt;
  selectElement.appendChild(optionList)
}

document.getElementById('colorDropdown').onchange = function() {
  let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = document.getElementById('colorDropdown').value;

  ctx.fill();
};
```

Comment: For some reason it's still not showing up for me :(

Comment: I updated my answer with a third change that I had to make, which I forgot about.. It's the variable name for `select` and `selectElement`. Did you make that change too?
Are you getting any errors on your console?

Answer (score 0):

Your element name is `selectElement` but you populate options into `select`. There are errors in `let selectElement = document.getElementById('#colorDropdown'),` also. Another error is the order of the statements in the for loop. Please check the snippet for the corrected code.

```js
var selectElement = document.getElementById("colorDropdown");
let options = ["BlueViolet", "Crimson", "DarkSalmon", "OliveDrab", "SaddleBrown"];
for (let i = 0; i < options.length - 1; i++) {
    let opt = options[i];
    let optionList = document.createElement("option");
    optionList.textContent = opt;
    optionList.value = opt;
    selectElement.appendChild(optionList)
}
document.getElementById('colorDropdown').onchange = function(){
let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
ctx.fillStyle = document.getElementById('colorDropdown').value;

ctx.fill();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Project 3</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Project 3">
<meta name="author" content="Kim Peoples">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="p3.css">
<script src="p3.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="colorDropdown">
        <option>Select a Background Color</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button onclick="clearCanvas">Clear Canvas</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: clearCanvas is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 28,
  "colno": 31
}

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Well, I fixed the error with populating options in the dropdown. But I didn't implement the `clearCanvas` function.

Answer (score 0):

you have error in your code :

`for (let i < options.length - 1; i = 0; i++)` this not right 
-> `for (let i=0 ; i < options.length; i++)`

```
<button onclick="clearCanvas">
```

-> `<button onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear Canvas</button>`

i have write for you with right code.

```
<head>
<title>Project 3</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="description" content="Project 3">
<meta name="author" content="Kim Peoples">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="p3.css">
<script src="p3.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="colorDropdown">
        <option>Select a Background Color</option>
    </select>
</form>
<button onclick="clearCanvas('#FFFFFF')">Clear Canvas</button>
<script>
    function init(){
        let selectElement = document.getElementById('colorDropdown');
        let options = ["BlueViolet", "Crimson", "DarkSalmon", "OliveDrab", "SaddleBrown"];

        for (let i=0 ; i < options.length; i++) {
            let optionList = document.createElement("option");
            optionList.innerHTML = options[i];
            optionList.value = options[i];
            selectElement.appendChild(optionList);
        }
    }
   init();
    document.getElementById('colorDropdown').onchange = function(){
     clearCanvas( this.value);
    };

   function clearCanvas(e) {
        let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        let ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = e;

        ctx.fill();
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I allowed myself to make some changes:

an function for initialize the select and i have combined the color change code whit the reset function.

bye

Comment: Does setting the color to `#FFFFFF` actually "clear" it?

Comment: no, she recreated a white square. if your background is white the square this masked.

Comment: if you need an realy clear -> save value of attributes, remove canvas, create an new, set Attribute and insert to last place ;)

let c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); let width = c.getAttribute ("width");
let height = c.getAttribute ("height");
 let id = c.getAttribute ("id");
        c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
        c = document.createElement("canvas");
        c.setAttribute("width", width);
        c.setAttribute("height", height);
        c.setAttribute("id", id);
        let b=document.getElementById("myForm");
        document.body.insertBefore(c,b);

Answer (score -2):

**This should work:**

```js
function update() {

  var color = ["undefined", "BlueViolet", "Crimson", "DarkSalmon", "OliveDrab", "SaddleBrown"];

  var y = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  var x = y.options[y.selectedIndex].value;

  document.getElementById("myCanvas").style = "background: " + color[x] + ";"

}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <br />
  <form>
    <select id="dropdown" onchange="update()">
   <option value="0">Select a Background Color</option>
   <option value="1">BlueViolet</option>
   <option value="2">Crimson</option>
   <option value="3">DarkSalmon</option>
   <option value="4">OliveDrab</option>
   <option value="5">SaddleBrown</option>
  </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown').value = '0'; document.getElementById('myCanvas').style = 'background: undefined;'" value="Clear Canvas">
  </form>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</body>
```

To add extra options, enter CSS color names, hex codes, or rgb codes to the `var color` array, as well as another `<option>` in the `<select>` menu, and set all the values to be consecutive integer, starting at 0 with the "Select a Background" option.



**A Cleaner Alternative:**

```js
function update() {

  var y = document.getElementById("dropdown");
  var x = y.options[y.selectedIndex].innerHTML;

  document.getElementById("myCanvas").style = "background: " + x + ";"

}
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas width="500" height="500" id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  <br />
  <form>
    <select id="dropdown" onchange="update()">
   <option value="0">Select a Background Color</option>
   <option>BlueViolet</option>
   <option>Crimson</option>
   <option>DarkSalmon</option>
   <option>OliveDrab</option>
   <option>SaddleBrown</option>
  </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('dropdown').value = '0'; document.getElementById('myCanvas').style = 'background: undefined;'" value="Clear Canvas">
  </form>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</body>
```

To add extra options, just add the CSS color name in between the option tags. 



(Note: the `<br />` tags are to add space between the at the bottom of the preview, so the stackoverflow console doesn't block the form. This shouldn't show up on a normal webpage.)

Comment: It needs to be populated from the javascript file, not options in the html

Comment: While this might "work" as the code goes it does not appear to actually use the colors the OP posted nor does it populate from the JS code as was asked thus fails to answer the question.

Comment: I updated the answer to (hopefully) answer your question better.