# How to Stop multiply a canvas line when the windows is resizing?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a function that draw a CANVAS line and make this get the same coordinates of a `<div>` by using `offsetLeft` and move its searching the same position of the `<div>`. It is working good.

```
 drawCanvas() {
   const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
   const lineH = c.getContext("2d");      
   c.width = window.innerWidth;
   c.height = window.innerHeight;

const positionCanvas = () => {
 const divPosition = document.querySelector('.myDiv').offsetLeft        

  lineV.fillStyle = "grey";
  lineV.fillRect(divPosition , 0, 2, window.innerHeight);
  lineV.fill();
}

positionCanvas() 

window.onresize = () => {    
  lineV.height = window.innerHeight; 
  positionCanvas()     
}
```

The problem is I don't know how avoid the default CANVAS behavior that duplicates many times the line when I resize the windows. How do I solve it? Thank you

Comment: Looks like you just need to clear the canvas?

Comment: How do I do it? I'm very beginer in using Canvas.

Comment: check this post in SO [Clear canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
  const positionCanvas = () => {
    lineV.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); //<-- new line added in the code
    //... rest of the code ommited
```