# How do you clear canvases in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codepen

https://codepen.io/MabelJane/pen/ROjONN

Hello, 
I have been creating a green screen algorithm on code pen which I have put a link to above. Most of it seems to be working except from the JavaScript that is supposed to clear the canvases. I think it will probably be something quite simple but I can't work it out. I put the code that I think is what doesn't work below. Thank you

```
function clear() {
    var fgCanvas = document.getElementById("can1");
    var bgCanvas = document.getElementById("can2");
    var fgContext = fgCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var bgContext = bgCanvas.getContext("2d");
    fgContext.clearRect(0, 0, fgCanvas.width, fgCanvas.height);
    bgContext.clearRect(0, 0, bgCanvas.width, bgCanvas.height);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clear the canvas for redrawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: Just rename your function name "clear()". It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Javascript doesn't like the function name you're using - **clear()** - thus the function won't ever be called. Try renaming the function to **clearIt()** or something like that. Apart from that your code for cleaning the canvases is correct.

Comment: Hello, I have now tried this but it still doesn't want to work. Do you think it could be anything else ?

Comment: I'm afraid renaming your function to canvas() doesn't help either. ;) As I suggested try renaming it to clearIt(). By the way, I just noticed there's a typo in your code now: `fgContext.clearRect(0, 0, fgcanvas.width, fgCanvas.Height);` Javascript is case-sensitive so fgcanvas isn't correct - make it fgCanvas

Answer (score 0):

Type clear in your console:

```
clear
ƒ clear() { [Command Line API] }
```

`clear` function is basically for clearing console terminal as far as I know, so just rename it or create an object and declare `clear` method as a property instead of declaring it for `window` object.