# What are the proper way to completly clear HTML5 canvas after globalComposite operation?

Tags: html, image, canvas

I know [this Q/A may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing) but using the solutions there I can't clear my canvas completely.
After I set the `globalCompositeOperation` of my context, my canvas still had some layer after calling `clearRect()`.

The `canvas.width = canvas.width` solution will do the trick, but [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing) says it is not supported in all browsers and also a bad practice.

How do we properly clear a canvas after globalComposite operation?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image();
const reader = new FileReader();
const filterRed = document.getElementById("red");
const addText = document.getElementById("addText");
const upload = document.getElementById("upload");

upload.addEventListener("change", function(evnt) {
  const file = evnt.target.files[0];
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    img.src = e.target.result;
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.height);
    };
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

filterRed.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // redraw image again to prevent double clicking
  // behave not normaly
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.filter = "contrast(0.6) brightness(100%)";
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "multiply";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});

addText.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // redraw all things again
  // but here not behave normaly
  canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    img.onload = function() {
      // using canvas.width = canvas.width solve the problem
      // but it is not the right way
      canvas.width = canvas.width;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.width);
      ctx.font = "50px serif";
      ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
      ctx.fillText("Hello world", 50, 90);
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<p>
  Upload Image First
</p>
<label for="upload">Click to select file</label>
<input type="file" accept="image/*|video/*" id="upload" hidden>


<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="red">
  red
</button>
<button id="addText">
  redraw with text
</button>
```

Here the reproduction [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-sound-ojq7q)

The image should not have a white layer on top of it, the text should be white not the image.

Comment: What's wrong with the accepted solution in the question you've linked to?

Comment: you probably want to check my code sandbox link first. This is 2019 and there is still no clear way to clear all style path etc on canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinitialize your context `globalCompositeOperation` to its default value: `source-over`.

Note that you may also need to reset the context transformation matrix to its default, this can be done by using `setTransform` method and an identity matrix `1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0`.

The only thing that may now block our clearRect from working correctly would be an active clipping rule. So when you use `clip()` be sure that you always did call `ctx.save()` before, and then call `ctx.restore()` afterward to disable the clipping region (or don't use `clip` at all).

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
draw_btn.onclick = drawStuffs;
simpleclear_btn.onclick = brokenClear;
better_btn.onclick = betterClear;

drawStuffs();

function drawStuffs() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,34,123, .75)';
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,45,45);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.translate(25, 25);
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,45,45);
}

function brokenClear() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
function betterClear() {
 ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
 ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
}
```

```html
<button id="draw_btn">draw stuff</button>
<button id="simpleclear_btn">simple clear (broken)</button>
<button id="better_btn">better clear</button>


<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot so `ctx.clearRect()` arent clear `fillStyle` `globalComposite` in canvas. Will change question title to related of `globalComposite`