# Empty/clear an element on the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, element, innerhtml

I got this small example where I am adding images to the DOM. I tried to create a function for clearing the element to where I am adding the images by:
`document.querySelector("#photo2").innerHTML = "";` but it didnt work as I expected.

How can I clear the element without reloading the page?

Here is my codepen: '
https://codepen.io/haangglide/pen/VwjqmZp

**Updated code with more comments in the code, i tried to make it more compact as well**

I think basically my problem is that Im creating new Image elements for each snapshot where i place the generated imageuri. I started creating multiple canvases but pretty soon it got very heavy.

**HTML**

```
<button id="btn" disabled>take a snapshot</button>
<button id="btn-remove">remove all the images</button>
<video></video> 
<canvas id="photo2"></canvas>
```

And my javascript

```
const vid = document.querySelector('video');
let images = [];

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true }) // request cam
.then(stream => {
  vid.srcObject = stream; 
  return vid.play(); // returns a Promise
})
.then(()=>{ // enable the button
  const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
  btn.disabled = false;
  btn.onclick = e => {
    train0Snap()
  };
  const btnremove = document.querySelector('#btn-remove');
  btnremove.disabled = false;
  btnremove.onclick = e => {
    clearAllImages();
  };
});

function clearAllImages() {
  document.querySelector("#photo2").innerHTML = "";
}

function train0Snap(){
  // set random position
  let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20); 
  let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);  
  let angleInRadians = (Math.random() * 0.2) - 0.1; 

  // 1) CREATING A CANVAS FOR DOING THE TRANSFORMATIONS IN
  const newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
  // Set width and height of thumb based on the video
  newCanvas.width = vid.videoWidth * 0.3; 
  newCanvas.height = vid.videoHeight * 0.3;
  
  // getting canvas 2D rendering context pf the created canvas
  const ctx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
 
  // centrate thumbsize 
  var xx = newCanvas.width / 2;
  var yy = newCanvas.height / 2;
  // create rotationmatrix
  ctx.translate(xx, yy);
  ctx.rotate(angleInRadians);
  
  // 2) DRAW THE VIDEO IN THE CONTEXT BASED ON THE NEW SIZE 
  ctx.drawImage(vid, -newCanvas.width /2 , -newCanvas.height /2, newCanvas.width/2, newCanvas.height/2); 

  // 3) GET THE CANVAS ELEMENT FROM THE DOM FOR DRAWING EVERYTHING
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById('photo2');
  // creating a rendering context for the output
  var ctxoutput = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  // creating a new Image element for each image and put it in the context
  var image2 = new Image();
  image2.onload = function() {
    ctxoutput.drawImage(image2, 20, 0);
  };
  
  // returns a data URI containing a representation of the image
  var canvasToUrl = newCanvas.toDataURL();
  // 4) SET THE IMAGESOURCE OF THE NEW IMAGE ELEMENT
  image2.src = canvasToUrl;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

```
function clearAllImages() {
  var canvas2 = document.getElementById('photo2');
  const context = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
}
```

Comment: Can you include an example with an image already on it or tell us how to add an image? I'm not clear on how images are added so I can't say how to remove them. you are doing something with the canvas, right?

Comment: Please create [mre], and what do you mean by it didn't work as expected? What happens? because `.innerHTML = ""` IS one way how you clear inner of element....

Comment: thanks. I updated my post with more comments and more compact code.

Comment: An `<img>` element is a void element, and has no `innerHTML` to clear; from the look of it `image2.remove()` should work.

Comment: unfortunately not. Actually I it was a typo when I edited my code.   ````document.querySelector("#photo2").innerHTML = "";```` was what I had from beginning but it doesnt work either unfortunately. (I edited my code above back to this)

Comment: As `#photo2` is a `<canvas>` element have you tried the answers from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing?

Comment: THANKS that works!