# Is there a way to make a rectangular area 0 alpha (transparent) after it has been drawn on to?

Tags: javascript, canvas, transparent

I've seen lots of questions asking how to draw a semi-transparent rectangle or other shape onto canvas after it's already been drawn to. My problem is that I want a rectangular area to be 0 alpha, but it seems to draw just nothing on top of what is there. I understand why that is (you are drawing 0 alpha on top of something that is already drawn), but I want those pixels 0 alpha. There has to be way.

Basically, I want to define an area that has 0 alpha after the canvas has already something drawn to it.

```
function fillPreviewClearColor(x,y)
{
    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.rect(x, y, 10, 10);
    ctx2.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)"; // I want NOTHING here
    ctx2.fill();    
    ctx2.restore();
}
```

Comment: Dup. of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2142535/8116884

Comment: That answer just seems to say how to clear the entire canvas.

Comment: The parameters to clearRect are (x, y, width, height), see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect.

Comment: That answer uses (0, 0, width, height) but it's a pretty straightforward jump to use other width and heights.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear the canvas for redrawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing)

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. Yes this should be closed maybe. The clearRect thing is so obvious.