# How can I clear all elements from a div canvas when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

On a website, I have a canvas (div) where "code blocks"(form) can be dropped. There's a button that should clear the canvas completely when clicked (so delete all code blocks that are currently in the canvas). How could I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing?

Comment: Canvas just draws whatever you want, but it loses it's context whenever it's drawn. You either have to save the coordinates of the codeblock to delete those specific ones. But more likely you just want to redraw the background :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.