# clearing the canvas on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clear the canvas when the "Eraser button is clicked. I wrote the JavaScript code, but somehow the canvas is not clearing. Below is my code:

```html
  <input asp-for="SignatureField" type=" text" placeholder="Type Here" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;font-family:Journal;font-size:40px" /><br/>
<input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Eraser" onclick="EraseCanvas()" /><br/>
<canvas  id="colors_sketch" width="500" height="200" style="border: 1px solid #ccc;"></canvas>
```

this is my JavaScript function to erase the content of both input box and Canvas:

```
<script>
    function EraseCanvas()
    {
        document.getElementById('SignatureField').value='';
        
       var canvas1 = document.getElementById("colors_sketch");
    
       var context = canvas1.getContext("2d");

        context.clear(0, 0, 500, 200);
       
        
    }

</script>
```

when I click the Erase button, the content of the input box are cleared, but canvas content do not get erased.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142535/how-to-clear-the-canvas-for-redrawing

Answer (score 2):

Use `context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 200)` instead of `context.clear(0, 0, 500, 200)`.

I hope I've answered your question :)